# How to keep logs of deleted files?

Tags: powershell

I made a script that deletes files older than 30 days. I want a log with the name and date etc of the files that were deleted. I want this every time a file is deleted.

Here's my code:

```
$dump_path = "C:\Test"

$max_days = "-30"

$curr_date = Get-Date

$del_date = $curr_date.AddDays($max_days)

Get-ChildItem $dump_path -Recurse | 
    Where-Object { $_.LastWriteTime -lt $del_date } |
    Remove-Item
```

Answer (score 2):

This is a great place to use the Tee-Object (or the alias, tee). This cmdlet allows you to save output to a file or variable **and** send it to the pipeline, as well. Here's a quick example you should be able to modify and incorporate into your script.

```
$DateTime = Get-Date -Format "DMM-dd-yyyy_THH-mm-ss"
Get-ChildItem C:\Test -Recurse | tee -FilePath "C:\Deleted Files-$DateTime.txt" | Remove-Item
```

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849937%28v=wps.620%29.aspx

Answer (score 1):

You can use the transcript feature, and add -Verbose to your Remove-Item:

```
Start-Transcript C:\somedir\transcript.txt -Append

$dump_path = "C:\Test"

$max_days = "-30"

$curr_date = Get-Date

$del_date = $curr_date.AddDays($max_days)

Get-ChildItem $dump_path -Recurse | Where-Object { $_.LastWriteTime -lt $del_date } | Remove-Item -Verbose

Stop-Transcript
```

That will also record any errors the script encountered.